# global security manager in flex

Tags: apache-flex, security, settings, sandbox

I made a swf that interacts with other site on the internet (which has a crossdomainfile for me).
in the main.mxml there is a definition of webservice (mx:WebService)(which is not in my domain). 
Therefore when loading the swf, there is a first call to crossdomainfile.xml.
I put this swf on my server so that my clients can get it.
When i connect to my server to download the swf, i expect to be asked if i want to allow the swf 
connect to foreign webservice domain. But i am not being asked.
Do i always need to define exception in Global Security Settings panel?
I don't want my client do define special things..
Is there a best practice for that? Why when i surfing the net other swf can do this? 
I read about the FlashPlayerTrust, can i define there a website i trust my swf will connect to?
anyone knows?

Comment: i am still working on the problem. Discovering this errors 
Error: Request for resource at https://other.domain.com/lib1/lib2 by requestor from https://127.0.0.1:8443/tar13/Main.swf is denied due to lack of policy file permissions.
*** Security Sandbox Violation ***
Connection to https://other.domain.com/lib1/lib2 halted - not permitted from https://127.0.0.1:8443/tar13/Main.swf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution is to add headers permission to the crossdomainfile: 
allow-http-request-headers-from

detailed info is in http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/403/kb403185.html

Answer (score 0):

You ask a bunch of questions, I'll try to explain the best I can.

The loading of the crossdomain.xml file will occur when you access the WebService located on 
the remote domain; not when the swf containing the WebService call is loaded.

If a crossdomain.xml file is not there; the error is returned to the Flash Player.  If you create a handler for that error, you can surpress that error from the user.  IF no handler exists, I believe a run time error is displayed--but I haven't tested that.

If you want to be asked whether the swf can access the foreign domain or not; I'm pretty sure you'll have to write that code yourself.

I've never had to deal with Global Security Settings or FlashPlayerTrust in situations where I need to access a remote service.